# Prove that $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)=-1$

Tags: induction, roots-of-unity

May you help on how to start, or where to look for the following question?

By using the $n$-th roots of the unity, show that:

- $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)=-1$
- $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\sin\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)=0$

Can we prove the above **by induction**? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Much easier if you know that $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$, then oan sum both at once and use geometric series rule.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, the hint included in the problem "By using the $n$-th roots of unity..." is a dead give-away, and since the OP is ignoring the hint entirely, it might be that he does not know what a $n$-th root of unity is.

Comment: Or perhaps OP is just seeking an alternate proof, or that is a second part of the problem as presented to OP. @DilipSarwate

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Actually, @ThomasAndrews is right in that I seek an alternative proof (it would be interesting if induction could be used).

Comment: There probably isn't a good way to do it by induction on $n$. That's because the relationship between $\cos 2k\pi/n$ and $\cos 2k\pi/(n+1)$ is tenuous at best. There *might* be a proof by strong induction by first proving it for $n$ prime, but it isn't trivial. Implicitly, the standard proof of this result uses the formula for the sum of a finite power series, which in turn is proved by induction. But the power series used for $n$ in this problem depends on $n$.

Comment: Of course, the sin formula is trivially true - because $\sin(2\pi(n-k)/n))=-\sin(2\pi k/n)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An answer not (explicitly) using roots of unity, which shows the geometry of what is going on.

Consider the points around a circle, $P_k=(\cos 2k\pi/n,\sin 2k\pi/n)$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$ (note, we include the case $k=0$, which is not in your sum.)

They form a regular $n$-gon, and a simple rotational symmetry argument shows that the center of mass:

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(P_0+P_1+\cdots + P_{n-1}\right)$$

is a point on the plane fixed by a rotation of $2\pi/n$ around $(0,0)$, and there is no such point other than $(0,0)$ (if $n>1$. If $n=1$...)

This means that $$P_1 + P_2+\cdots + P_{n-1} = -P_0=(-1,0).$$

This also explains why it is hard to find an inductive proof of this - the transformation step from a regular $n$-gon to a regular $n+1$-gon is not simply "adding a point." You'd have to do a lot of moving around of the points, which makes it hard to see how you could use the result for $n$ points to get a result for $n+1$ points.

(The division by $n$ is an unnecessary part above, but it lets us evoke the intuitive term "center of mass.")

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**
Compute 
$$e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}} + \cdots + e^{i\frac{2(n - 1)\pi}{n}}$$
then compare real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $n$-th roots of the unity $z$, we have $1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1}=0$, i.e. $$1+(\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})+(\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})^2+\cdots+(\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n})^{n-1}=0,$$ by De Moivre's formula, we have $$1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)+i\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\sin\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)\right)=0,$$ which implies that $$1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\cos\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)=0,$$ and $$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}\right)+\ldots+\sin\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n}\right)=0$$

---

Update: we couldn't get any relation formula on $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ and $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n+1})$ if consider induction on $n$, even if we separate the question into even/odd parts. But the even case is easy since $$\cos\frac{2j\pi}{n}+\cos\frac{(n+2j)\pi}{n}=0,$$ hence the summation only left $\cos\pi=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Complement to @Solitary's answer:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 2}$ and let define $\mu_n$ the set of the $n$th roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. One has: $$X^n-1=\prod_{\eta\in\mu_n}(X-\eta).$$
Examining the terms of degree $n-1$, one gets: $$-\sum_{\eta\in\mu_n}\eta=0.$$

Comment: It's actually trivial by Vieta's formulas.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Which is what this answer is implicitly using, just not invoking the name. (I knew these formula for quite a long time before I learned the name Vieta, and I still don't use that name most times because I think of it as "obvious" in a way that doesn't require a name.)

Comment: I have never heard this name before and I agree with the second part of @ThomasAndrews' comment.